# Save properties of windows service (Wix Installer)

Tags: c#, wix, windows-services

I´m using wix to generate a installer of a windows service. I´m need to save "backup" the properties like "Log On" and "Recovery" and when I install a new version of the windows service apply this properties again. The idea is that this properties don´t lost.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set these as part of your install of the service.

For LogOn, see the Account property on the ServiceInstall element. It also has a Password property if you're using a user account that isn't built-in and uses a password. Not needed if you're using one like NT AUTHORITY\LocalSystem.
http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/serviceinstall.html

For setting recovery options, check out the ServiceConfig element from the WixUtilExtension: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/serviceconfig.html

Comment: Thanks @NickRamirez But If this properties changed manually in the list of windows service, How I get this properties and apply when install a new windows service. Or how I set up this properties programatically?

Comment: From an ease-of-use perspective, I would not want a user to have to change the properties of a Windows service via services.msc. Ideally, you'll set these either during your install or as part of a UI maintenance screen in your application. For setting it during install, WiX supports creating a user interface wizard that lets the user select these things and then use those user-set values when installing the service.

Comment: For backing up properties, that's not really the realm of an installer. I'd do it in your application (do you have a "maintenance" GUI?) and then save the settings the user sets in a file somewhere or in the registry. Then have the application reuse that file/settings the next time you install. Applications often save this sort of thing in %apdata% or %programdata%

Answer (score 0):

You can store your settings for the service in  exe.config